# Transmission won't launch script after download on Ubuntu Server 18.04.2

Tags: command-line, server, scripts, automation, transmission

I am on a completely fresh install.

After installation I have only installed Transmission. (`transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon`)

Then I created a file under `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads` named `script.sh`:

```
echo "Test" > test.txt
```

I have changed ownership of the file and made it executable:

```
$ sudo chown debian-transmission script.sh
$ sudo chgrp debian-transmission script.sh
$ sudo chmod 775 script.sh
$ sudo a+x script.sh
```

After this I have modified my setting.json so it executes the script:

```
"script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/script.sh",
```

And yet, after I add a torrent to the web interface it just does not lauches the script after the download is completed.

I am strugling with this for 2 days now and have no idea whatsoever. I wasn't abled to turn on logging either.

Any idea is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you really know that it is not running or you just can't find the file ? Where do you look for `test.txt` ? Maybe you should give full path to know where the file will be?

Comment: I look for `test.txt` next to the script file, since if I run it manually it creates it there. `killall -HUP transmission-daemon` finds no process and I restart my deamon after the changes made in `settings.json`. `sudo a+x script.sh` makes the file executable for all users. `transmission-daemon` owns the folder.

Comment: Yes, but that assumption is wrong. It creates the file from where `transmission-daemon` is running. When you run it manually it creates a file from where you run it. `sudo a+x script.sh` will give an error.

Comment: I managet to see the logs via `sudo journalctl -u transmission-daemon.service` and in fact the issue was that the path wasn't the full path: `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have to specify a full path for the output file in the script:

```
echo "Test" > /var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but I was having the same issue. This was with a Synology NAS but I remember having a similar issue years ago. While the solution sounds silly, it works, first, create a simple shell script that cd's to the directory where the script is, then call the actual script you want to run. Not sure if it's a transmission thing. That and when I previously ran it on a pi I changed the permissions so the service was running as me and it put all the config files in my home directory. Either way, the below should work with zero permission changes as long as all the permissions are good.

cd /volume1/share/scripts
./runthis.sh

Then in runthis.sh, have what you really want to run. Since I added the mounted share through the Synology web gui I knew the permissions were fine. Also, and you probably have but I also ran chmod u+x runthis.sh and the same for the launch.sh script also. That is what I always run to make a shell script executable but a+x may do the same thing